# Add id to clickable footerview in ListView

Tags: android, listview

Is it possible to add an id to an added footerview? For example when extending baseadapter it is possible to change the returned id to whatever. This is easier to work with than position. Is it possible to do this when adding a footerview that is clickable, so that onItemClick will return an id?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a custom view which you call as footerview. If that is the case you can code the way you want the view to react to the required events as you need in the custom view class that you create.